# Are there any use cases for List when Deques and Arrays are available?

Tags: design, design-patterns, array, list, queue

I've been thinking about this over the past few weeks, and I've come up with no good arguments.  My perspective is from Java, but if anyone has any language-specific cases outside of this language, I'd love to hear them.

It seems to me that the benefit of using a List over a Deque comes from the fact that one can access the elements within directly via index numbers.  While I can see the use in something like a UI (e.g. having a drag-and-drop sortable list), when talking about pure code interaction I see three cases for this:

1. Iteration.  Iterating with a `for` loop using `get(i)` and `size()` is expensive in most implementations, and can usually be better done with `iterator()`, which is present in every `Iterable` collection.
2. Lookup by index.  This usually requires a table of indices and a fixed length list, in which case one would get better performance out of an array.
3. Operating on the front or back of a `List`.  This is what `Deque` was designed for, and it doesn't require any calls to `size()`.

`Collections` support is nice, but the only thing I could find offhand that was implemented in `Collections` but not `Arrays` was a `shuffle()` function, which is fairly simple for an experienced programmer to implement (or delegate to `Collections`, since the overhead for non-primitive arrays isn't too bad IMO).

**I feel that everything that one would need a `List` for can be better filled by either a `Deque` or an array.**  I've done some searching for comparisons, but the only info I've found either doesn't really discuss `Deque`s or is written as a "Welcome to Programming" thing and doesn't offer a direct comparison of use cases.  I've looked over my code for the past few years and haven't found any `List`s outside of UI elements; I usually use a `Set` or a `BlockingQueue` for storing variable-length data.

Comment: You might be right about `Deque` but in Java (at least) *arrays* have **fix size** which is simply a nogo in most of *my* use cases.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware.  But for variable-length data I'm suggesting using a `Deque`.  `ArrayDeque` is an implementation with about the same performance as `ArrayList`, and `LinkedList` also functions as a `Deque`.

Comment: then I simply see it the other way around: i don't use *arrays* unless I have a really good reason to do so.

Comment: If you can give the reasons you prefer `List`s to arrays for fixed-length data, I'd love to read about it.  Programmer opinion, language semantics, and expected behavior are all important factors in choosing a construct.  You can feel free to post an answer if you feel like you have enough material for one.

Comment: Re, "2. Lookup by index...get better performance out of an array."  Performance is not an issue when comparing `java.util.List` with `java.util.Deque`.  They are _interfaces_.  Performance is only an issue when you choose an implementation.

Comment: *"If you can give the reasons you prefer Lists to arrays for fixed-length data, I'd love to read about it."* lt gives me freedom to later change my mind and having that data not being fix length. It makes me think deper on my collection: Do I need index access? Do I need douplicates? Do I need to preserve order? Do I need to apply order? The only thing *arrays* give out of the box is *preserve order* and *index access* and require some effort to adopt the others. Using *collections* the effort is to choose the right implementation...

Comment: @jameslarge The cheapest implementation (outside incredibly edge-case implementations supplied by `Collections` wrappers) would be `ArrayList` which, at best, had the same performance as an array. In #1 I mentioned "most implementations", and that applies throughout: `ArrayList` and the unstructured N-element collections supplied by `Collections.toList(...)` are the primary exceptions.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Arrays can do everything you mentioned except have variable length. A `Deque` will do everything you mentioned except have index access.

Comment: *"Arrays can do everything you mentioned except have variable length."* They automatically remove duplicates without any sopporting logic around like Javas `Set` would do? They automatically reorder entries while I add them as Javas `TreeSet` does? must have missed that.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Of course not, that's a property of those collections. `List`s and `Deque`s can't do that, either. It's outside the scope of the question. You mentioned having duplicate elements, and arrays 100% support that. I'm not trying to replace everything with those two options, just `List`s.

Comment: Your comments make it clear this is just an angry rant and not an earnest question.

Comment: @RubberDuck I'm not angry, nor am I ranting.  This is something I've given a lot of thought to, and I'm surprised nobody is giving me any serious feedback.  It's something I've spent hours searching for, both on the Internet and combing through open source projects and JDK.

Answer (score 8):

**A `List` is *general* and flexible.**

Generalized structures are ideal for return values in business, web, and desktop applications. It's not optimal to return a `Deque` or an `Array` if your consumers will be converting to `List` in most cases *anyway*. It's potentially *less* efficient. And, it clutters your consumers' codebases with boilerplate conversions and/or utility libraries to deal with your "more efficient" interfaces.

To be clear: Some structures, like `Deque`'s and `Array`'s are certainly more efficient *for **particular** use cases*, but a `List` is sufficiently efficient for *most use cases*. `List`'s may be over-used. But, in many domains, the performance hit of using a `List` over a more well-suited structure is negligible — not even worth a second thought.

Compound that with work-effort versus business value: Choosing a data structure that supports the precise interface I need *and no more* requires mental effort and *time*. And those are *costs* to the business. *Sometimes* there's a corresponding increase in value. But, in many applications there isn't — neither the business nor the customers will see any difference if you swap your `List` out for a more-optimized `Deque` when you're piping 50 rows from the database through your model to your view. (Or whatever.)

**That said, there *are* use-cases that are well-served by `List`'s.**

The "need" for a `List` is more obvious in long-lived, stateful applications, where collections can stick around and be mutated over a long period of time. A text editor, for example, shouldn't automatically create a `data[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS]` array of arrays. And, you certainly *could* create an array of arrays with some default sizes and scaling behaviors and add methods for insertions and deletions. But, that's precisely what the `List` interface already *does* for you. (And the existing implementation already well-tested and optimized!)

**My "2 cents":** Unless your domain is small, very well-defined, or performance-critical, start with general collections and optimize later. The flexibility is immediate valuable in most business and web applications. Whereas the performance edge is negligible.

And don't forget about stateful applications, where a `List` interface is more often precisely what you'll end up *reinventing* if you've defaulted to an array or `Deque`...

---

<sup>Examples of things where you might favor efficiency over flexibility might include things like system code (OS, driver, firmware), a VM, or other types of "platform" code — like a modern web browser's internal DOM implementation or JavaScript execution engine.</sup>

Comment: So you're arguing that public-facing APIs should use `List`s over arrays to avoid confusion/hassle? I can completely see that argument. But for internal use, I still feel my points are valid.

Comment: Well, not just in the sense of distributed libraries or web API's, if that's what you mean. I mean "internally" too, I usually prefer to consume (and therefore *return*) `List`'s [when appropriate].  Even within a class, I default to a `List` over a `Queue`, `Deque`, or `Array`, because the performance implications don't often outweigh the downstream flexibility. Just bear in mind, my advice applies to business systems and web stacks, which I sense *most* of us (at SE.SE) work on. If you're writing a VM, OS, driver, or firmware, my advice might be the opposite: Favor performance.

Comment: FYI, I realize my answer didn't cite a specific example of where a `List` interface is actually preferred. And, I don't want to give the impression that "I don't know what my callers need" is the only reason for a `List`. ... So, I'm working on working a more specific use-case in.

Comment: The text editor example confuses me.  Wouldn't a `StringBuilder` be the tool for the job, with perhaps some sort of helper class?  I feel like, while an array of arrays isn't the tool for the job, surely a `List` of `List`s isn't any better.

Comment: @ndm13 Probably not. A `List` of `StringBuilder`'s is probably good. But, a straight-up `StringBuilder` will leave you parsing and *re-parsing* a giant blob when you draw/redraw the characters. If you've already got the character stream separated (indexed) into lines, and you know your scroll position, it's super-efficient to jump to `lines[scroll_top_line]` (or whatever) and just start drawing...

Comment: ... and of course, if you've got any sort of formatting or syntax highlighting going on, your `StringBuilder` loses its effectiveness at the line-level too. You'll probably want a Token list of some sort. Stuff you probably want to *overlay* instead of embed into the underlying character data. ... Moot point though. Bottom line is, there are situations where the `List` interface would have to be re-invented if we avoided using a `List`. ... Which you're free to do with a `StringBuilder` or an `Array` if you like. ... ... Or you could just use a `List`.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason to use `java.util.List` instead of using `java.util.Deque`?

Yes.

`java.util.List` has methods to access elements by position.  `java.util.Deque` does not.  If you are implementing an algorithm that *needs* to access elements by position, then `Deque` is not going to work.  The contrapositive is true as well:  If your algorithm only needs to look at the items in sequence (i.e., if you can use an `Iterator`), and if it only needs to mutate the sequence at the two ends (or one end, or not at all), then a `Deque` will work for you.

The guiding principle is pretty simple:  Choose an interface that defines the methods that your application needs to call.

---

Is `java.util.List` a well-designed inteface with a clear purpose?

IMO, No.  It tries to be too many different things.  If I want you to call my function that will randomly access the list elements, then I am *not* going to allow you to pass in just any `List`.  I am going to *make* you pass in an `ArrayList`, or maybe, if we are collaborating on a project where it makes sense to have a lot of custom classes, we will define an interface that defines exactly those operations that my code is going to perform on your list.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but I'm curious: what types of algorithms would require a `List` of variable length?

Comment: Nothing *requires* a `List`. A `List` is just an easier abstraction than a `Deque` or `Array` for algorithms that perform `List`-like operations, like [`Add(int,obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-) or [`Remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-). If I write a simple text editor and a user is actively pressing keys, I want the collection(s) underlying the UI/view code to expose a highly dynamic interfaces. I don't want my view resizing arrays or streaming through a `Deque` for every keystroke.

Comment: For UI, I 100% understand the need for `List`s: an indeterminate number of elements are getting rendered on a (screen|terminal|page|etc) in a certain order, and they need to be referenced by location.  Outside of that, though, I feel like you could substitute any `Iterable`.

Comment: There are a *lot* of applications that contain long-lived, stateful collections beyond a desktop UI's. It was a single example. I'm sure you can think of other applications that don't fit the request-response model most of us deal in.

Comment: I can't think of any use case, other than within a UI where a user would be providing an index based on regularly updated, variable length information, where it would be necessary to have an index-addressable collection of variable length.  That's the purpose of my question: for index-addressable collections of fixed length, arrays perform better, and for non-indexed collections, a `Deque` or another `Iterable` can typically provide all necessary functionality.

Comment: @ndm13, re "arrays perform better."  If a naked array performs better than an `ArrayList`, the performance boost is only going to be O(1).  I would not allow that concern to influence architectural choices.  That's something I'd only worry about toward the end of a project, after everything else has been taken care of, and only if it actually proved to be a real problem.

Comment: @jameslarge I mostly agree. `ArrayList` has about 3 method calls of overhead on average per access. Also, `List.of(...)` and `Arrays.asList(...)` have virtually no overhead, so I have no issue with using one of those too provide `Iterable` support (indeed, JDK uses these almost exclusively).